# What is the origin of the word "pigra"?

Tags: etymology

Zamenhof coined this word, but I don't understand how he came up with it. I only find it similar to *pig* in English and *gras* (fat) in French, but it is maybe accidental.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pigra#Esperanto), it comes from the Italian word *pigro*, whose feminine form is exactly the same as the Esperanto *pigra*. The Italian word in turn comes from the Latin word *piger*.